# PHP shell_exec() issue

Tags: php, linux

I am having an issue using the PHP function `shell_exec()`.

I have an application which I can run from the linux command line perfectly fine. The application takes several hours to run, so I am trying to spawn a new instance using `shell_exec()` to manage better. However, when I run the exact same command (which works on the command line) through `shell_exec()`, it returns an empty string, and it doesn't look like any new processes were started. Plus it completes almost instantly. `shell_exec()` is suppose to wait until the command has finished correct?

I have also tried variations of `exec()` with the same outcome.

**Does anyone have any idea what could be going on here?**

There are no symbolic links or anything funky in the command: just the path to the application and a few command line parametes.

Comment: does the php\Apache suer have permission to run the application?

Comment: Can you run any other command with `shell_exec()`/`exec()` etc.? Try `echo exec('whoami');`

Comment: @Dagon: How can I check this?

Comment: @Brett, You ran script from cli or from web browser?

Comment: It could be a path issue - have you tried supplying `shell_exec()` with an absolute path to your application?

Comment: @Dor: I ran echo exec('whoami'), and it came back as wwwrun. So this is probably the problem. Would you know how to give wwwrun permissions to my application?

Comment: Depends what kind of setup you have... Do you have suexec enabled? What is the path of the program that you try to execute? Try having another script file located in the same place of your program, but with `whoami` as it's code. Would it execute properly? This is how you check if the problem relates to the path or to the content of the file...

Answer (score 0):

Some thing with you `env`

See output of `env` from `cli` (command line interface) and `php` script
Also see what your shell interpreter?

And does script and cli application runs from one user?
If so, se option [safe_mode](http://ru.php.net/manual/en/ini.sect.safe-mode.php#ini.safe-mode)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the user apache is running on (probably www-data) has access to the files and that they are executable (`ls -la`). A simple `chmod 777 [filename]` would fix that.

By default PHP will timeout after 30 sec. You can disable the limit like this:

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);
?>
```

**Edit:**

Also consider this: http://www.rabbitmq.com/

Comment: the user appears to be wwwrun. But the application permissions are -rwxrwxrwx, so it appears as if the user shouldn't matter. Any more thoughs?

Comment: Just that this is silly and you should really consider other methods. Could you post the scripts you're trying to run and the php code that's supposed to run them? And maybe tell us a little more about it?